# Автоматическое обновление данных таблицы в sqlite studio (python,sqlite3)

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли возможность в приложении sqlite studio (с помощью python,sqlite3) автоматически обновлять таблицу при внесении в нее новых данных, НЕ используя кнопку "обновить данные таблицы" (указано ниже)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А чем вас эта кнопка не устраивает?)

Comment: Хочу видеть изменения в реальном времени